# How to dynamicly assing LIMIT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query

```
SELECT *
LIMIT 3, (6 - 3)
```

Wchich returns:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6 - 3)' at line 2`

I basicly want to select 6 rows `*` from 3-rd row, in MSSQL it's `WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 3 and 6` but dynamicly knowing `:from` and `:to` parameters instaed of `:from` and `:size`

Comment: SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT 3,3

Comment: I hate to use substarction there, I want to dynamicly compute it using `:from` and `:to` parameters instead of `:from` and `:size`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE `OFFSET` in this case

```
SELECT name 
FROM your_db 
ORDER BY your_column DESC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constant.

Basically if you're not in a stored procedure or a prepared statement you can't do it.

- Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
- Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using
  integer-valued routine parameters or local variables

So, inside a stored procedure, the following would work:

```
declare from_row bigint; 
declare to_row bigint;
SELECT name 
FROM your_db 
ORDER BY your_column DESC 
LIMIT from_row OFFSET (to_row-from_row);
```

Comment: But still how to dynamicly get number for offset? `LIMIT :from OFFSET :to - 1` gives error `right syntax to use near '- 1'`

Comment: Just a side question, how you would put DECLARE and SELECT in the same query? Using PDO and am limited to just one.